# Not able to execute a php file in phonegap android platform

Tags: cordova

I am using PhoneGap inside Eclipse to try to write some android apps.
After done with the PhoneGap hello world tutorials, I decided to follow a slightly more complex tutorial, and I have to connect to my local database first.

So I decided to use a index.html and a db.php inside assets/www directory first.

Here is my index.html code:

```
<?
require('db.php');
require('utils.php');
require('header.php');
?>
    <div  data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
    <h1>JQuery</h1>        
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">

<? 
//more thing go here....
?>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
    Footer
    </div>
    </div>
<? require('footer.php'); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

and the db.php:

```
<?
$mysql_db = "test123";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_link = mysql_connect("localhost", $mysql_user, "");
mysql_select_db($mysql_db, $mysql_link);
echo "display me";  
?>
```

The problem is that the **display me** inside the db.php is not displayed on the first page of my apps, which means that the db.php file is not getting executed.
But the index.html was displayed successfully.
Please help :)

Answer (score 3):

PHP is a server side technology. You need an interpreter on your web server in order to be able to run PHP code. All of the files in assets/www are loaded client side in a WebView. The WebView does not include a PHP interpreter so your PHP code will not run.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right, PhoneGap is a html/css/js thing.
So how to I make all kind of database operation without using php in PhoneGap?

Comment: Use AJAX to call your PHP web service.

Answer (score 0):

you can either connect to your php server and retrieve database info through ajax ( like any other web browser) or use a "local" db provided by sqllite which phonegap supports. check phonegap api for examples of the local db or use of localstorage. docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/cordova_storage_storage.md.html